# Android Options Menu not showing

Tags: android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I have four options in the options menu, and put 3 items as ifRoom option, but in the screen there is space yet only two items are showing. So to truly test if there is no space I made the first 3 items as always and they show just fine. Any idea?

[image]

This is the code:

```
package com.techiequickie.bharath.parsetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Listbets extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listbets);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.standard_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_newbet:
                Toast.makeText(Listbets.this, "newbet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_earnings:
                Toast.makeText(Listbets.this, "earnings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_myaccount:
                Toast.makeText(Listbets.this, "myaccount", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_viewbets:
                Toast.makeText(Listbets.this, "viewbets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        //int id = item.getItemId();

        /**noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);*/
    }
}
```

Also another question is how can I change the activity name to my appname across all the activities? Where is this code added? In my case my app name is BOA but it is showing as ListBets which is in fact the activity name.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with the action bar recently and I think your problem arises because of **spacing** issues between the icons. If you **must** have the icons shown use:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/item"
        android:title="@string/action_item"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

To set the Title:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle("BOA");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listbets);
}
```